# Regular expression to capture text starting with "NE" followed by any one or two digits apart from 61 to 71

Tags: php, regex

I'm searching through uk postcodes.

I want to capture all text beginning with `NE` followed by any numbers apart from numbers 61 to 71 using `regular expressions` in `PHP`.

Example of valid matches:

```
NE1, NE17, NE49
```

Invalid matches:

```
NE61, NE70
```

I've tried and such like

```
NE((?!(6[1-9]))|(?!(7[0-1])))
```

Comment: Please check your requirements. You accepted a `NE(?!(6\d|7[01]))\d+` solution, later changed to `NE(?!(6[1-9]|7[01]))\d+`, but it also matches `NE115179` like strings while the requirement is *to find `NE` followed by any **one** or **two** digits*. It will also match `NE1` in `ONE1` which might be the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough `NE(?!(6[1-9]|7[01]))\d+`. (Edited based on @Wiktor Stribiżew observation)

https://regex101.com/r/T8Cy4C/9

Comment: The `NE(?!(6\d|7[01]))\d+` regex does not match the code with `60`, while the requirement  is to match `NE` with two digits "apart from 61 to 71". It also matches `NE115179` like strings while the requirement is to find `NE` *followed by any one or two digits*. It will also match `NE1` in  `ONE1` which might be the code.

Comment: If you start fixing the regex following my comment, you will have the same solution I have posted. So, the question seems to be unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
\bNE(?!(?:6[1-9]|7[01])\b)\d{1,2}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YDokpQ/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - start of a word (here)
- `NE` - `NE` substring
- `(?!(?:6[1-9]|7[01])\b)` - no `6` and then `1` through `9` or `70` or `71` followed with a word boundary allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary (here).

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/bTrGS):

```
$s = "Example of valid matches: NE1, NE17, NE49 Invalid matches: NE61, NE70";
if (preg_match_all('~\bNE(?!(?:6[1-9]|7[01])\b)\d{1,2}\b~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => NE1  [1] => NE17  [2] => NE49 )
```

Comment: IMHO this is the answer to the question ++